# Редактирование страниц в админпанели WP

Tags: wordpress, редактор-текста

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где искать! В консоли ВП в меню "Страницы" не загружается страница для редактирования. При чем только одна. Все остальные страницы редактируются. Проблема возникла после добавления и обновления новой информации на страницу. При этом страница на сайте отображается с внесенными изменениями. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Искать начинать с анализа логов и кода страницы.
Но проще - удалить эту страницу и создать новую.

*ЗЫ. небось каким-нить конструктором страницы созданы?*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да страница создана на Visual Compozer

Comment: Это зло. Ошибочно считать что они облегчают работу. Как раз наоборот. И создают ещё кучу всяческих проблем. Рекомендую не использовать никакие конструкторы.

Comment: Учту на будущее.